# Vectors in C++ , bucket sort : Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, vector, stl

In my code, I am trying to implement bucket sort and in my implementation I have tried using vectors, but unfortunately I end up with errors with respect to vector functions.

Code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void bucket_sort(vector<float> & , int); //vector is passed by reference


int main(){

vector<float> array;
float element;
int count;


cout << "\nEnter the size of the vector : ";
cin >> count;

cout << "\nEnter the elements into the vector : ";

for(vector<float>::size_type i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
    cin >> element;
    array[i].push_back(element);
}

bucket_sort(array , count);
}

void bucket_sort(vector<float> array, int count){

    vector<float> bucket;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
        int bucket_index = count * array[i];
        bucket[bucket_index].push_back(array[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
        sort(bucket[i].begin() , bucket[i].end());

    int index = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
        for(int j = 0 ; j < bucket[i].size() ; j++)
            array[index++].push_back(bucket[i][j]);
}
```

Errors :

```
bucket_sort.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
bucket_sort.cpp:24:12: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘array.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<float, std::allocator<float> >(i)’, which is of non-class type ‘float’
   array[i].push_back(element);
            ^
bucket_sort.cpp: In function ‘void bucket_sort(std::vector<float>, int)’:
bucket_sort.cpp:36:24: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘bucket.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<float, std::allocator<float> >(((std::vector<float>::size_type)bucket_index))’, which is of non-class type ‘float’
   bucket[bucket_index].push_back(array[i]);
                        ^
bucket_sort.cpp:40:18: error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘bucket.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<float, std::allocator<float> >(((std::vector<float>::size_type)i))’, which is of non-class type ‘float’
   sort(bucket[i].begin() , bucket[i].end());
                  ^
bucket_sort.cpp:40:38: error: request for member ‘end’ in ‘bucket.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<float, std::allocator<float> >(((std::vector<float>::size_type)i))’, which is of non-class type ‘float’
   sort(bucket[i].begin() , bucket[i].end());
                                      ^
bucket_sort.cpp:45:33: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘bucket.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<float, std::allocator<float> >(((std::vector<float>::size_type)i))’, which is of non-class type ‘float’
   for(int j = 0 ; j < bucket[i].size() ; j++)
                                 ^
bucket_sort.cpp:46:19: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘array.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<float, std::allocator<float> >(((std::vector<float>::size_type)(index ++)))’, which is of non-class type ‘float’
    array[index++].push_back(bucket[i][j]);
                   ^
bucket_sort.cpp:46:40: error: invalid types ‘float[int]’ for array subscript
    array[index++].push_back(bucket[i][j]);
```

Edited code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void bucket_sort(vector<float> & , int); //vector is passed by reference


int main(){

vector<float> array;
float element;
int count;


cout << "\nEnter the size of the vector : ";
cin >> count;

cout << "\nEnter the elements into the vector : ";

for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
    cin >> element;
    array.push_back(element);
}

bucket_sort(array , count);

cout << "\nSorted vector : ";

for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
    cout << array[i] << " ";
 }

void bucket_sort(vector<float>& array, int count){

vector<float> bucket[count];

for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
    int bucket_index = count * array[i];
    bucket[bucket_index].push_back(array[i]);
}

for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
    sort(bucket[i].begin() , bucket[i].end());

int index = 0;

for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
    for(int j = 0 ; j < bucket[i].size() ; j++)
        array.push_back(bucket[i][j]);

}
```

Edit :
I have introduced the correction with respect to the push_back() but now upon running my code I hit a segmentation fault. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're attempting to call `push_back` on an element of the vector, rather than the vector itself.

Comment: you can't do like `array[i].push_back..`. you are not trying to push in the vector but rather into the element of the vector which is `float`, giving you the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push_back` is method of `vector`, not element. To append element (with increasing vector size by 1) use `array.push_back(123)`. To assign something to element use `array[i] = 123`.

If you want to fill vector using assignment, you have to resize vector first: `array.resize(count)`.

To sort, wirte `sort(array.begin() , array.end())`.

`bucket[i][j]` is totally incorrect: `bucket` is one dimensional vector. You probably want `bucket` to be `vector<vector<float>>`.

---

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
    int bucket_index = count * array[i];
    bucket[bucket_index].push_back(array[i]);
}
```

You have only `count` elements in `bucket` array but ask for `count * array[i]` element.

Comment: Thank you , very much! It compiles successfully.

Answer (score 1):

## Your code have many problems.

Main problem is following:

You can not do this:

```
    array[i].push_back(element);
```

You must do this instead:

```
    array.push_back(element);
```

Later you do the same:

```
    bucket[bucket_index].push_back(array[i]);
```

But this time, probably you need just:

```
    bucket[bucket_index] = array[i];
```

Or if you want just to obtain a copy from vector called "array", you can just do:

```
    bucket = array;
```

If you post comment what `bucket_sort` should do, I can provide future explanations.

Finally, I also would suggest you to add:

```
    using MyVector = vector<float>;
```

Will safe you lots of typing.

Also you might define the function to use the vector by reference, because else it is copied and you probably do not want this:

```
void bucket_sort(MyVector &array, int count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `array[i].push_back(element)`, use `array.push_back(element)`. Element will go at the position automatically as a for loop index.

So, at the end of loop, array will have count number of elements as desired by you.

Use this logic everywhere in the code.