# Segmentation problem using vectors (implementing Bucket Sort in C++)

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdvector, bucket, bucket-sort

I'm working on an implementation of the Bucket Sort algorithm that uses vectors. In the first loop a **Segmentation Fault** is raised and I can't see it why. Before posting this question I've been looking similar ones (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131591/vectors-in-c-bucket-sort-segmentation-fault) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131591/vectors-in-c-bucket-sort-segmentation-fault)) but I haven't found the answer there.

The implementation is taken from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bucket-sort-2/). Since it is publish here I had supposed that it should work, could be a problem related with the compiler (I'm using *g++*)?

The fragment of code is this one, just changed the name of some of the variables from the original example:

```
void bucketSort(float arr[], int n){

    vector<float> buckets[n];  

    // Here is where the bug must be!!
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int bi = n * arr[i]; // Index in bucket
    buckets[bi].push_back(arr[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        sort(buckets[i].begin(), buckets[i].end());
    }

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        while (!buckets[i].empty()){
            arr[index++] = *(buckets[i].begin());
            buckets[i].erase(buckets[i].begin());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this driver code to test it:

```
int main(){
    float arr[] = {8.0, 9.231, 1.31, 3.1, 42.2, 4.3, 99.999};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    cout << "Length of the array: " << n << endl;

    cout << "Original array: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    bucketSort(arr, n);

    cout << "Sorted array: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using `std::vector` then just use it. Don't mess around with `sizeof()` math in `main()`. You should also use `std::vector<std::vector<float>> buckets` as mixing vector and arrays is just plain weird.

Comment: `buckets` is an array of `n` elements. `bi = n * arr[i]` would, in general, be greater than `n`. `buckets[bi]` then exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: Your `arr[6]` is `99.999`. `n * arr[6]` will be 6 * 99.999, or `599.994`. Then, `buckets[599.994].push_back(...something...)` is not going to have great chances of success. You may wish to invest some time in learning how to use a debugger which would've easily showed you this flaming wreckage going down, one statement at a time.